# Вставить html в php правильно

Tags: php, html

Как правильно здесь вставить тег `</span>`. Сейчас строчка кода выглядит так:

```
if(!empty($arResult['PROPERTIES']['TOWN']['VALUE'])){
    echo $l.'г. <span itemprop="addressLocality">' . 
trim($arResult['PROPERTIES']['TOWN']['VALUE']).$district;
    echo'</span>';
```

Сейчас тег  захватывает лишнее и его необходимо поставить перед переменной $district, но не могу понять, как это сделать корректно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($arResult['PROPERTIES']['TOWN']['VALUE'])){
    echo $l.'г. <span itemprop="addressLocality">' . 
trim($arResult['PROPERTIES']['TOWN']['VALUE']).'</span>'.$district;}
```

Comment: Я надеюсь, я правильно понял поставленную задачу.

Comment: не совсем, тег <span itemprop="addressLocality"> на своем месте, а закрывающий тег нужно переставить перед .$district

Comment: Отредактировал.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Только фигурная скобка лишняя. Не знаю, лишняя ли она вообще или только в моем случае (т.к. приведенная мной строчка кода вырвана из общего).

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !empty( $arResult[ 'PROPERTIES' ][ 'TOWN' ][ 'VALUE' ] ) ){
    echo sprintf( '%sг. <span itemprop="addressLocality">%s</span>%s',
        $l, trim( $arResult[ 'PROPERTIES' ][ 'TOWN' ][ 'VALUE' ] ), $district );
}
```

Comment: поясните пожалуйста свой вариант? Почему именно так? Какие у такого варианта преимущества?

Comment: @Alla это, конечно, моё субъективное мнение, но на мой взгляд так гораздо нагляднее. Вы воспринимаете строку целиком и видите, куда какие значения подставятся. ИМХО, это намного удобнее, чем искать их в каше из точек и кавычек. Вы вольны взять тот вариант, который ближе лично Вам :)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я возьму его себе на заметку ) А каша там знатная..